# xpages in browser only

Tags: redirect, xpages, xpinc

I am developing a Domino application using xpages, however I would like the use of the application to be only via browser.
As in the company where I work there are many applications developed for Notes client, I would like the user When you click the application icon in the Notes workspace, is redirected to the browser.

Is the right way to use the context redirect, or is there another way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

i can't find the ressource/link for the solution anymore....I'am not the owner of that solution, just found it a while ago in the web.

1. In the application properties set the option "Notes client Launch" to "Launch first attachment in "About Application""
2. In the "About" document add  a html-file with following code:

```html
<body onLoad="openPage()">

<script>
function openPage(){
 window.location.href = "your_URL"
}
</script>
```

This should open your URL when you click on the db icon in your client workspace.

Comment: You need to add a little more. Users could right click and navigate to a view.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the database events to do a @UrlOpen. Make sure to add a check so e.g an Admin or the application owner can still access it in Notes for checks and maintenance.